# Linq returning multiple copies of row 1 (count is correct)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to delete some rows from a table, ready to add in the new data (can't overwrite as isn't a fixed number of rows). My LINQ statement is returning the correct count of rows - but it's just repeating the first rows data over and over. Also note - AsNoTracking() does fix the initial problem, but I then I can't use the data after my initial query is done. So this won't help.
Here's my code....

```
        try
        {
            var Dtos = 
                DbContext.Appointments
                    .Where(i => i.OutletId == currentOutletId)
                    .Where(i => i.Department == "S")
                    .Where(i => i.Date >= startOfWeekDate)
                    .Where(i => i.Date <= endOfWeekDate)
                    .ToList();

            if (Dtos.Any())
            {
                DbContext.Appointments
               .RemoveRange(Dtos);
                await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

          //Write my Add rows code here

            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

[Breakpoint and hover over dto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wEYP.png)

New on site so I can't post the image direct sorry. When I break point and hover the dto after the ToList - I get these 21 rows returned. The 21 rows should cover a full week on timeframes. With AsNoTracking applied, I get the full week no problem. Without it, I get 21 copies of index 0.

Comment: `.Where(i => i.Date >= startOfWeekDate &&  i.Date <= endOfWeekDate)` put that in one statement. `but it's just repeating the first rows data over and over` have you checked for duplicates in `Dtos`, what data exists in `Dtos` after the call `ToList`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I've tried with the .Where statements all in one and I get the same result.
I only get correct data in the dto when I use AsNoTracking. Without it, I get copies of the first row (correct count of rows). But I need to use the query in RemoveRange() so AsNoTracking() is no good for me.

Comment: When your ready to add @ "//Write ...", you could try using a new context.

Comment: I'm looking forward to the write part hah :D Gotta get these removes done first!

Comment: CAn you show a screenshot of what you mean by the first row repeating ? Why do you have two contexts?

Comment: if you explicitly do a `.Select(x => x.PrimaryKey)` do you get the correct number of results _and_ the correct ids back or is it still the first records ids over and over?

Comment: @ CaiusJard I've added a screenshot to the description.
@Marco I've just tried adding .Select(x => x.PrimaryKey, x.Date) before my ToList. I get the correct count and the date is enumerating correctly! I'll see if I can extend this :)

Answer (score 0):

The database had four of the columns marked as keys. I needed to add the [Key] attribute to all of them on the model. I then had to add the type and order below the [Key]. Once it knew what order those keys are in, it enumerated perfectly. Thank you again for everyone who commented to help.